# Quoting literal causes no results to return

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT v.id 
FROM visitors v
LEFT JOIN trackings t on v.id = t.visitor_id
WHERE v.app_id = 'xxx' 
  AND (field = quote_ident('app_name') 
  AND string_value ILIKE quote_nullable('test_app'))
```

Problem is that the query fails to return any results when I use `quote_nullable` on the `string_value`. It only works with `quote_ident`, but that is not the appropriate function as far as I understand here.

Example in pseudocode of how I am building the query serverside (using pattern matching on the filter (starts_with, ends_with etc.).

```
filter = user_params["filter"]
field = user_params["field"]
value = user_params["value"]

...
"starts_with"       -> "(field = quote_ident('#{field}') AND string_value ILIKE '#{value}' || '%')"
"ends_with"         -> "(field = quote_ident('#{field}') AND string_value ILIKE '%' || '#{value}')"
"contains"          -> "(field = quote_ident('#{field}') AND string_value ILIKE '%' || '#{value}' || '%')"
"does_not_contain"  -> "(field = quote_ident('#{field}') AND string_value NOT ILIKE '%' || '#{value}' || '%')"
```

Later in the DB, I invoke a stored procedure that looks something like

```
          filter_length := COALESCE(array_length(filters, 1), 0);
          filterstring := array_to_string(filters, ' OR ');

          IF filterstring = '' or filterstring is null THEN
              filterstring := '1=1';
          END IF;

          sql := format('
                      SELECT v.id FROM visitors v
                      LEFT JOIN trackings t on v.id = t.visitor_id
                      WHERE v.app_id = app_id and (%s)
                      group by v.id
                      having case when %s > 0 then count(v.id) = %s else true end
                  ', filterstring, custom_filter_length, custom_filter_length);
          RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
```

Where `filters` is an array of conditions (the ones I built earlier)

Any ideas?

Comment: Your condition actually is equal to `... field = 'app_name' and string_value ilike '''test_app'''` after applying the functions...

Comment: I fail to see why you need to use `quote_ident` (which is for *identifiers* not for values) or `quote_nullable` on a constant value. What are you trying to do there? Why do you think you need those functions?

Comment: I use a EAV design for the trackings table to allow users uploading custom data.

"app_name" and "test_app" are dynamic values and they query is being built at the application layer

Comment: Added a pseudocode example of how I am building the queries serverside